# gitlab - trying to clone a repo gives error that network is unavailable

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, git-clone

I'm trying to clone a repo from our internal gitlab server.

I'm running windows 10 and with an ubuntu sub system.  I have putty agent running ... and i have my bash environment set up so that as soon as I start bash, my key is loaded and so I just need to do this to sign into a remote server:

```
jj@DESKTOP-123:/mnt/c/Users/$ whoami
jj

jj@DESKTOP-123:/mnt/c/Users/$ ssh -A root@test.mydomain.com
Warning: Permanently added 'test.mydomain.com,1.1.1.1' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Linux test.mydomain.com

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Thu Jul  2 10:52:31 2020 from 2.2.2.2
root@testserver:~#
```

On gitlab, under my profile / avatar, i added my public key to the ssh keys section.
Then I try to connect from bash on ubuntu like so

```
jj@DESKTOP-123:/mnt/c/Users/jj/source/repos/gitlab$ git clone -v git@mygitlabserver:team/documentation.git
Cloning into 'documentation'...
ssh: connect to host mygitlabserver port 22: Resource temporarily unavailable
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I also tried connecting as "jj" or "root" instead of "git" user.

I'm not sure what I'm missing / doing wrong.

Comment: File permissions maybe? That's all I can think of. SSH is clearly working.

Answer (score 0):

As illustrated in [`WSL` issue 2278](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/2278), the error message `port 22: Resource temporarily unavailable` generally points to a firewall issue:

> do this: `sudo ufw allow ssh` or if you wanna be specific on ssh port(22) do `sudo ufw allow 22`.
>
> To check if firewall added properly: `sudo ufw status`.
>
> This thing actually happens when you do `sudo ufw enable` and forget to add a ssh or port 22 firewall.

Comment: This differs from the Windows firewall (https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4888#issuecomment-585434704)